Finding nullspace of differential operator
I'm interested in finding all stress fields $\sigma^{\alpha \beta}(u^1,u^2)$ that solve the following linear homogenous partial differential equation:
$$ \partial_\alpha\left[\sigma^{\alpha \beta}(u^1,u^2) \partial_\beta \mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2)\right]=0$$
Here, the stress field is symmetric under index exchange, $\sigma^{\beta \alpha} = \sigma^{\alpha \beta}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ is a real, smooth three-dimensional field corresponding to a solid, curved two-dimensional surface embedded in three (Euclidean) dimensions. Both $\sigma, \mathbf{r}$ are subject to periodic boundary conditions such that increasing either argument $u^i$ by 1 does not change their value.
For an arbitrary smooth surface $\mathbf{r}$ I'm interested in numerically finding all possible stress fields. I'd also be interested in analytically proving that there are at least three such stress fields, which I expect (but don't know how to prove) from the fact that the integral of the left-hand side of the equation over the surface (which corresponds to the net force induced by the stress) must vanish in each of its three components.
Any ideas on how to get started? Thanks!
